# create and insert randomly duplicates

Tags: python, random, duplicates

This is not probably a common question but I want to CREATE duplicates and INSERT it randomly in my String. Just like the following example.

I have this file :

```
AppleStrawberryBananaCitrusOrange
```

And I expected this kind of output :

```
trusppleStrawbeApplertrusryBananaCitrusOrangepple
```

In this case my program randomly select a substring of length '4' : 'pple' and 'trus' and duplicates him 'twice(2)'  before the insertion.

I think that I could run the program by using the fonction copy with copy.copy() and copy.insert() but I don't really know how to use it randomly.

For the moment;I just write the part of the code for read and write and something else:

```js
import copy

chain='*'
contain = ''

file= raw_input ('Filename:')


x = open(file,'r')

for line in x:
  
if not(chain in line):
 contain+=line
 e=copy.copy(contain[4:8])
 f=copy.copy(contain[8:12])


y = open('copi','w')


y.write(contain)
y.write(f)



x.close()
```

Result:

```
AppleStrawberryBananaCitrusOrange
awbe
```

As you can see; it doesn't really work like I want. :(

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do.

You'll probably need a library for random selection:

```py
import random
```

Now here is your input string:

```
s = "AppleStrawberryBananaCitrusOrange"
print s
```

You can use `random.randint` to select a random position and extract a 4-character word:

```
i = random.randint(0, len(s) - 4)
w = s[i:i+4]
print w
```

Finally, you can select two more random positions and insert the word via string concatenation:

```
for j in range(2):
    i = random.randint(0, len(s) - 4)
    s = s[:i] + w + s[i:]
print s
```

Output:

```
AppleStrawberryBananaCitrusOrange
yBan
ApyBanpleSyBantrawberryBananaCitrusOrange
```